# Territory2Id no longer visible to partner users?

Tags: apex, schema, territory, spring19

Since Spring 19 release got pushed to our sandboxes, we've had a bunch of problems with the community we're working on.

I've been debugging and seem to have isolated this issue.  If I enter the following code in the anonymous window:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> m = Schema.SObjectType.ObjectTerritory2Association.fields.getMap();
```

I get this keyset:
associationcause, id, isdeleted, lastmodifiedbyid, lastmodifieddate, objectid, sobjecttype, systemmodstamp, territory2id

If I run the same code while logged in as a partner user, here is the keyset returned:

associationcause, id, isdeleted, lastmodifiedbyid, lastmodifieddate, objectid, sobjecttype, systemmodstamp

Territory2Id is now missing.  This is posing some issues and is breaking a lot of pieces of the community that are referencing a class which references these objects.

I should mention that going to Territory Settings loads this error:
**Aura Integration Service Error"An internal server error has occurred**

I'm trying to work w/ Salesforce Support about this, but wanted to check with the community at large to see if there are any steps people might recommend I pursue to try and resolve on my own.

also: this has been working in Production for months.  So a little concerned that once Spring 19 works its way up, it could become a bigger issue.

Comment: It's not something I own, so I can't make an authoritative statement, but please pass along to support to look at W-5620625 in gus - that should help them with some relevant analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a valid bug, which was resolved.